# How to open a link start with itms-apps in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, url-launcher

I am using url_launcher package, I can open the links and mails easily with this but I tried opening itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions to give the users an option to cancel the subscription in iOS but I am getting an exception.

```
_launchURL(String _url) async => await canLaunch(_url)
      ? await launch(_url)
      : throw 'Could not launch $_url';
```

for the above, normal URLs are opening but the above mentioned is not opening.

Comment: Try this
`openURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

for non Http requests you need to do some work in your main.dart file. write and intinlize this class in your main.dart file.

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
@override
HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
return super.createHttpClient(context)
  ..badCertificateCallback =
      (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
}
}
```

In your main.dart

```
HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
```

Hope it will resolve your problem.